# Mysql PHP Ловим массив на новой странице

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli

Есть страница с подробным описанием товара, у каждой свое `id`. Пользователь переходит на нее с другой страницы, допустим страница rent на ней выводятся результаты поиска и нажав по нужному товару, человек переходит на страницу `ads.php`

Когда пользователь переходит на нее, нужно с помощью PHP и правильного запроса `Mysql` вытащить массив данных по `id`.

`id` получаю так:

```
$id = htmlentities($_GET[‘id’]);
```

`id` прекрасно выводится на каждое объявление, а вот весь массив нет, знаю что проблема в запросе к Mysql, но не знаю как правильно сделать. Варианты гуглил, тестировал, но результат не получил.

Если ставить в Mysql запрос конкретный номер, например 35 то массив вытаскивается этого объявления, а мне нужна переменная.

Сейчас массив не вытаскивается, делаю так, не показывает вообще ничего, даже в print_r():

```
('SELECT
     rent.id, 
     rent.year, 
     rent.run, 
     rent.town_sell,
     rent.price, 
     rent.description,
     rent_photo.photo AS img,
     mark.title AS mark,
     model.title AS model,
    city.title AS town_sell
   FROM rent
 INNER JOIN mark ON rent.mark = mark.id
 INNER JOIN model ON rent.model = model.id
 INNER JOIN city ON rent.town_sell = city.id 
 
  LEFT JOIN rent_photo ON rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
  WHERE rent.id IN (ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ АЙ ДИ) 
  ORDER BY rent.time_upload DESC');
```

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Сейчас у Вас сложность в том, чтобы корректно передать переменную в запрос?

Comment: @Denis640Kb   верно. Ставил $id в запрос, но массив его не видит. Там может добавлять нужно $_POST или в скобки правильно обрамлять, пробовал разные варианты, ответа не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример запроса на php PDO:

Файл подключения к БД. 
`dbase.php`

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=yourDB;host=DBip;charset=utf8', 'DBlogin', 'DBpass');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Файл с запросом:

```php
require 'dbase.php'; // Подключаем БД


$id = htmlentities($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT
     rent.id, 
     rent.year, 
     rent.run, 
     rent.town_sell,
     rent.price, 
     rent.description,
     rent_photo.photo AS img,
     mark.title AS mark,
     model.title AS model,
    city.title AS town_sell
   FROM rent
 INNER JOIN mark ON rent.mark = mark.id
 INNER JOIN model ON rent.model = model.id
 INNER JOIN city ON rent.town_sell = city.id 
  LEFT JOIN rent_photo ON rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
  WHERE rent.id = :id 
  ORDER BY rent.time_upload DESC"; // Запрос
$req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$req->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();
$array = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Получаем данные
if($array){
    print_r($array); // Выводим результат
}
```

Comment: К сожалению код не сработал, выводит следующую ошибку.   Uncaught [HY093] - SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound trace

Comment: Ваш ответ был очень близок, я немного переделал запрос. В строчке нужно было написать вот так:  WHERE rent.id = '.$id.'   Спасибо огромное за неоценимую помощь!